# Why was the highly upvoted answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

The following answer to [the question about the Islamic state](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22411/did-snowden-reveal-that-isis-is-a-usa-israel-tactic) was deleted after being well recieved for many days and logical closure of the question:

The reason given was "does not satisfy rules of the site". But I see no rule broken

Comment: Please allow me to point you to this question: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/shoutout-to-moderators-stop-deleting-wrong-answers It discusses whether answers should or should not be deleted if they are considered to be bad by some. Please let your opinion be known by voting for the various answers.

Answer (score 2):

I removed it because it is not actually an answer to the question. It is an extended comment on related issues, but it does not answer the question whether ISIS is a Mossad/CIA creation.

My comment is a bit ambiguous, the emphasis should have been on "not an answer", which is a common SE concept and one of the pre-defined flag reasons.

Comment: It does actually answer the question and bring to light the real intentions of Isis which substantiate that it is impossible for it to be an american creation, rather a long term strategy which appears to be counter intuitive to external observers but within the Islamic framework it is reconciliable  ...